# Setting a variable from HTML area

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want that a text is shown when one of the conditions is met.
Problem is that I can't set the variable showText. Can anybody give me an hint?

```
@if ((condition_1) || (condition_2) || ... || (Condition_n))
{
    @showText=True;
}

@if (showText)
{
 //Show the text!!
}

@code
{
    public bool showText{get; set;}=false; //default value is false
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer (that I posted from a mobile) to have a code example

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to set a variable based on conditions, an event is the correct place to do that. It could be some app-specific event, a click on a button, or a lifecycle event like `OnInitialized`. That's where your `if(conditions){ showText=true; }` should go.

```
<button @onclick="@HideText">hide text</button>
<button @onclick="@ShowText">SHOW text</button>

@if (showText)
{
    @theText
}

@code
{
    bool condition_1 { get; set; }
    bool condition_2 { get; set; }
    bool Condition_n { get; set; }
    public bool showText { get; set; } = false; //default value is false
    string theText { get; set; } = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        condition_1 = false;
        condition_2 = true;
        Condition_n = false;
        EvaluateTextVisibility();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    void EvaluateTextVisibility()
    {
        if (condition_1 || condition_2 || Condition_n)
        {
            showText = true;
        }
        else
        {
            showText = false;
        }
    }

    void HideText()
    {
        condition_1 = false;
        condition_2 = false;
        Condition_n = false;
        EvaluateTextVisibility();
    }

    void ShowText()
    {
        condition_1 = true;
        condition_2 = false;
        Condition_n = false;
        EvaluateTextVisibility();
    }
}
```